# Specs2 unit specification referencing

Tags: scala, specs2

I've got the following spec:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.{After, Specification}
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import org.specs2.specification.core.{Fragment, Fragments}

class TestRefSpec extends Specification {

  "My Spec" >> new iii {
    xxx(i)
  }

  def xxx(i: Int) = {
    def e1 = {
      println(s"** $i > 0")
      i must be_>(0)
    }
    def e2 = {
      println(s"** $i < 100")
      i must be_<(100)
    }

    "i should be > 0" >> { e1 } 
    "and < 100" >> { e2 }
  }

}

trait iii extends Scope with After {
  val i = 142

  def after = println("finalising")
}
```

The idea is that there is a spec that tests behaviours of something and then there are the target(s) represented by the Scope(s) that the behaviours are tested for. 
Ideally the behaviours would sit in a separate trait.
Alas when I run it though the output I'm getting is as follows:

```
[info] TestRefSpec
[info] + My Spec
[info] Total for specification TestRefSpec
[info] Finished in 560 ms
[info] 1 example, 0 failure, 0 error
```

Which means the tests do not really run.

Does anyone know how do I actually achieve what I'm intending to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are wrapping `xxx(i)` method call in a `new iii {}`.

This can't work, as the code inside the curlies is executed in the constructor of the new anonymous class extending `iii` and the result of the whole expression is a subtype of the `iii`, not `Fragments`, so the internal structure of examples, you construct and return from inside of `xxx()` method, can't make it to the specs2 `>>` operator.
Normally only the individual examples are - preceded by specs2 `in` operator are wrapped in a scope.

This will work:

```scala
class TestRefSpec extends Specification {

  "My Spec" >> {
    xxx(42)
  }

  def xxx(i: Int) = {
    def e1 = {
      println(s"** $i > 0")
      i must be_>(0)
    }
    def e2 = {
      println(s"** $i < 100")
      i must be_<(100)
    }

    "i should be > 0" in new iii { e1 }
    "and < 100" in new iii { e2 }
  }

}
```

Comment: I see. This approach, however, tightly couples the scope with the examples. Is there a way I can separate them? 
The reason I'm using the Scope here is that one of the implementations of the thing I'll be testing needs a clean up at the end.

Comment: I think I've figured it out now. I'll make xxx accept the instance of the thing I'm testing and AfterAll to close to the whole test.
Many thanks for the explanation what;s wrong with my initial approach